# react-native what is the difference between MainActivity.java and MyApp.java

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add a custom font. I see here a file being referenced called MyApp.java in the directory location where I find MainActivity.java.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1167

Should I edit this file, or create a new one?

Thanks for you input. Below I have provided gists for

AndroidManifest.xml

https://gist.github.com/Kielan/d1a5ab8641dfced953cdc572b932ecd8

MainActivity.java

https://gist.github.com/Kielan/fcaa07a5456d720af9711eece58988b7

Answer (score 0):

An Android app only has one `Application` class - so if it already exists, then you shouldn't make another one.

The reference in your link is for the AndroidManifest.xml. You'll need to specify your `Application` class there. When you do, you can add a style to it.

The full docs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Edit: If you don't have an application class, you can simply add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<application android:theme="@style/YourThemeHere">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris, I still do not fully understand.

In my current application I don't think that I see an Application class in code.  I do see markup in AndroidManifest.xml referring to mainActivity but not a myApp

I have edited my answer to include a gist for both files I have found inside src/main 

I want to confirm that 

 `android:name=".MainActivity"`

means that the name of my app is sort of dynamically referenced in MainActivity.

Comment: Well you don't need an Application class for simple apps. Use `<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">` in your AndroidManifest.xml instead. Edited my answer to reflect this.